# How to change the email structure in magento

Tags: magento, email

how to send the sales flat order details into the email? In the sales flat order table we have the delivery date column; how to send this details into the mail?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to override `sendNewOrderEmail()` function inside

app/code/Core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

and inside `setTemplateParams()` you can pass what ever parameter you want to pass.

Comment: yes that i know but i have installed the vendor module and in the email of vendor module i want to send the data

Comment: you can use  public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null) function where in $var array you can pass the data what you want

Comment: use below link which help you http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-sending-custom-emails